# How to define a bijection function from A\B to B/A

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, piecewise-continuity

how to construct a bijection from A\B to B\A.
I was thinking of defining a function that gets an element that is contained in the set A but not in B and "makes" the element to be contained in B but not in a.

but I don't know to write such a function

Comment: There is no such bijection in general. Where did you find this?

Comment: That's really funny because if I set $A=\Bbb R$ and $B=\emptyset$ then there can **NOT** exists any bijection between $A\setminus B$ to $B\setminus A$.

Comment: "I was thinking of defining a function that gets an element that is contained in the set A but not in B and "makes" the element to be contained in B but not in a." Yes, that's an accurate description of what $f\colon A\setminus B\to B\setminus A$ is.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such bijection in general. For instance, if $B\subset A$, then $A\setminus B$ has elements, but $B\setminus A$ is empty.